# c# and HTTP Handlers

Tags: c#

I recently joined a new c# project in which a console application is being developed and used as a server. A flex program is developed to handle the front-end (perform crud operations).

To communicate with this URLS from front-end to c# application, inside c# tiny httpserver code is used which is a free source. For example, from the browser a post method is passed like `http://localhost:portnumber/item/detail/1010?method=post...` 
then c# receives this request and does the process and response back in the form of xml.
This flex application is stored inside the webroot folder of c# application's debug folder.

Now the new requirement is that instead of Tiny Httpserver code the project team wants to use IIS. As I am new to this type of application and fresher too, please let me know some suggestions and some link where I can go through the concept.

As I googled a lot to understand the new requirement concept, but no idea how to find the link.

Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance,
Ramya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at Nancy:

http://www.nancyfx.org/ and the docs at: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Documentation

It's perfect for what your describing. And I think you'll be able to reuse a lot of you code.

You'd be able to write something like this:

```
public MyModule : NancyModule
{
    public MyModule()
    {  

        Get["/item/detail/{id}"] = parameters => {
            return new Detail(parameters.id).AsXml(); //this is pseudocode offcourse!
        };
    }
}
```